# create sql update for each control in vb6

Tags: sql, vb6, foreach, controls

So I've got this code to loop through each controls in a form and create and update sql based on their names and values, text or caption.

```
Dim sql as String
Dim ctr as Control

sql = "update table set "
For Each ctr In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctr Is TextBox Then
        If ctr.Container = "Carton Config data input" Then
            sql = sql & ctr.name & " = " & "'" & ctr.Text & "',"
        End If
    ElseIf TypeOf ctr Is OptionButton Then
        If ctr.Value = True Then
            sql = sql & " status = '" & ctr.Caption & "',"
        End If
    ElseIf TypeOf ctr Is CheckBox Then
        If ctr.Value = 1 Then
            sql = sql & ctr.name = "'OK',"
        ElseIf ctr.Value = 0 Then
            sql = sql & ctr.name = "'',"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

After that I add the where conditions of course but it doesn't matter now.
The problem is when it gets to a checkbox, the sql's value will be "False" and I have no idea why.
The length of the string shouldn't be a problem, the first checkbox that makes this is the 4th object, so the string is not too long. Besides, without the checkbox part, it works like a charm.
So could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered data binding?

Comment: That's also a good idea.

Let's see... I have a datagrid with a bunch of data from a datatable. When the users presses F2, it will show a frame to edit the active row's data.

Is it possible to setup the control to use the chosen row? As I know I can only setup the datasource and datafield. Well I could if I create an adodc object and modify it every time the user opens this form I guess.

Comment: Just a minor thing I noticed here:


`sql = sql & ctr.name & " = " & "'" & ctr.Text & "',"`


You have an extra ampersand and set of quotes, you could just write:


`sql = sql & ctr.name & " = '" & ctr.Text & "',"`

Comment: And very subject to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem so I will just answer it for those who might need it.
It was a simple syntax error:

Just replaced:

```
If ctr.Value = 1 Then
   sql = sql & ctr.name = "'OK',"
ElseIf ctr.Value = 0 Then
   sql = sql & ctr.name = "'',"
End If
```

With:

```
If ctr.Value = 1 Then
    sql = sql & ctr.name & " = 'OK',"
ElseIf ctr.Value = 0 Then
    sql = sql & ctr.name & " = '',"
End If
```